# nginx ignores one of every two request

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx 1.12.2 (downloaded from official site) on windows 8.1 as a reverse proxy server. I got a problem that one of every two request is ignored.

nginx config:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my_fake_domain.com;
        access_log C:/nginxlogs/access.txt;
        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_read_timeout 1800;
            proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
        }
    }
```

my nodejs server:

```
    'use strict';

    const http = require('http');

    const httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('okay');
    });

    httpServer.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

I'm using postman to send test requests. A request to `http://my_fake_domain.com` after a succeeded request will always loading. This always loading request does not actually ignored. If I cancel it, it will show up in the access log.

Note that a request to `http://localhost:8080` always succeed.

Where might I get wrong?